# What are the appropriate lookup formulas to solve a data problem in Excel?

Tags: excel

[image]

Pls look into this data and solve the data,
as I have tried various lookup formulas but unable to get the result.
I think find and lookup formula is used but I don't how to use.
I hope you will response to my query .
I request you to solve the data
thank you

Comment: vlookup(), hlookup() and index() with match() can all be used. You will find examples in the Excel help and also on here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `XLLOKUP()` with wild card matching option.

```
=XLOOKUP("*"&G2&"*",A2:A10,B2:B10,,2)
```

[image]